# Is there any provision to provide reference to the paper which is in process to get published in journal at the time of graduate applications?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, online-publication

I will be presenting my paper to a conference this month. The papers presented in the conference will usually take 3-6 months to get published and indexed in the journal.

While applying for admissions in next 2 months, I will not have any online reference to submit to the admission committee, because the paper might not have published until then.

So, is there any provision or any way using which I will be able to share the paper/publication with the admission committee?

Comment: Are you allowed to put the paper on arXiv or whichever common preprint repository is used in your field (if any)? If so you can just include a link from there to your CV and any other profiles you have.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer would be no since different conferences have different procedures. For the one of interest to you they may have something such as pre-publishing to arXiv or similar. This is appropriate for your CV:  "...to appear".

But you can also just say that your paper has been accepted to the conference that will be held on date future. You can also send them a copy of the paper if you like and they will accept it. And you can offer to send it in any case.